# Mercurial (hg) to gitlab migration using fast-export

Tags: git, gitlab, mercurial

I have number of mercurial repositories on Debian (7,8,9,10) that need migration to gitlab.
I was trying to do it in the same folder that original hg repo is located.

```
cd new-git-repo
git init
../../fast-export/hg-fast-export.sh -r . --force
git remote add origin https://github.com/xxx/new-git-repo
git checkout HEAD
```

However, this results in number of untracked files (all of the directories/files), and deleted files. The git checkout HEAD results in error

```
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
    .hgignore
    Makefile
    config
    configure/CONFIG
```

Can fast-export be done in-place?

Clarification is much appreciated.

Comment: Why would you create the git repo INSIDE the HG repo? Just make it in a new folder outside the hg working directory. Then when you are all done, you can delete / archive the original HG repo.

Comment: The code runs specific hardware, and needs to sit in specific location on each system. Over last 10 years it was backed into hg repo. I am now migrating few hundred of these hg repos to the gitlab. It is fine if it points to both repos for now. We plan to stop using mercurial in the future.